# Github Authentication using php-github-api

Tags: php, api, rest, github, laravel-4

I am trying to implement Github authentication in my application (built using Laravel 4) using [php-github-api](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api/blob/master/doc/security.md) by KnpLabs. I went ahead and created an app in my Github account to obtain the client_id and the secret key.

The problem is, I cannot authenticate using this library. A null result is returned. It implementation seems simple but I cannot get it work. Checkout how I am implementing it.

```
try{
        $client = new Github\Client();

        $auth= $client->authenticate('myclientid','mysecret',AUTH_URL_CLIENT_ID);

        $emails = $client->api('current_user')->emails()->all();

        return Response::json(array("user"=>$emails));
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return Response::json(array('failed',$e->getMessage()));
    }
```

This is the result I get from the above:

```
 ["failed","Requires authentication"]
```

Please someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a shameless plug, but it will help you see what the client is sending back and forth using Runscope. Create a free account, note your bucket key, then add this line after you create the client: `$client.setOption("base_url", "api-github-com-yourbucketkey.runscope.net");`. Then make the request again and view in your Runscope account. Then you can see the actual HTTP request/response generated and the error Github is returning.

Answer (score 1):

I believe 
`AUTH_URL_CLIENT_ID`
should be
`Github\Client::AUTH_URL_CLIENT_ID`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Github matter rather than a php-github-api question, really:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/user/emails?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy"
```

will fail too, whereas:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/user/emails" -u mbontemps
```

works just fine.

I think the reason is that client_id and client_secret authenticate an **application**, while the second command authenticates a **user**.

It's like you're asking: *"hey, application, tell me your emails"*.
And the app is answering: *"wait, what? I'm no user, dude!"*

So IMO you'll need to authorize the application for your user (which will give you a token) and then use this token to authenticate with the OAuth mechanism.

cf. http://developer.github.com/v3/#basic-authentication

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Update, `Github\Client::AUTH_URL_CLIENT_ID` no longer used. Please see:

https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api/blob/v3.3.0/doc/security.md

Supported methods are:

- Github\Client::AUTH_CLIENT_ID
- Github\Client::AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
- Github\Client::AUTH_JWT

In this case `$client->authenticate('myclientid','mysecret',AUTH_URL_CLIENT_ID)` should be:

```
$client->authenticate('myclientid', 'mysecret', Github\Client::AUTH_CLIENT_ID)
```

If using auth token, we can ommit the mysecret/password part:

```
$client->authenticate('myauthtoken', Github\Client::AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```